# Calculate Total disk i/o by a single process

Tags: linux, bash, process, io, disk

I am looking for some tool that will dump total disk I/O by a single process after it ends.
So far my finding is :-

- **iotop**= It shows i/o per process in real time but does not give
  total after process end.
- **iostat**= It shows real time I/O but
  does not tell process

*For example*, I have some process running in background with PID ####. I need the Total Bytes **Written** and **Read** by that process in total after the process ends.Can anybody tell how I can extract this information given a process PID.

Comment: Take a look at `/proc/<PID>/io` and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3634088/3776858

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feel free to play with this scribble (myio.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash 

TEMPFILE=$(tempfile)    # create temp file for results

trap "rm $TEMPFILE; exit 1" SIGINT  # cleanup after Ctrl+C

SECONDS=0               # reset timer

$@ &                    # execute command in background

IO=/proc/$!/io          # io data of command
while [ -e $IO ]; do
    cat $IO > "$TEMPFILE"   # "copy" data
    sed 's/.*/& Bytes/' "$TEMPFILE" | column -t
    echo
    sleep 1
done

S=$SECONDS              # save timer

echo -e "\nPerformace after $S seconds:"
while IFS=" " read string value; do
    echo $string $(($value/1024/1024/$S)) MByte/s
done < "$TEMPFILE" | column -t

rm "$TEMPFILE"          # remove temp file
```

Syntax: `./myio.sh <your command>`

Examples:

- `./myio.sh dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1G count=4096`
- as root: `./myio.sh dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/null bs=1M count=4096`

Please change dd's `of=` in last example only if you know what you are doing.

---

With this simple script from me you can watch an already running process and its IO.

Syntax: `pio.sh PID`

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$1" == "" ] && echo "Error: Missing PID" && exit 1
IO=/proc/$1/io          # io data of PID
[ ! -e "$IO" ] && echo "Error: PID does not exist" && exit 2
I=3                     # interval in seconds
SECONDS=0               # reset timer

echo "Watching command $(cat /proc/$1/comm) with PID $1"

IFS=" " read rchar wchar syscr syscw rbytes wbytes cwbytes < <(cut -d " " -f2 $IO | tr "\n" " ")

while [ -e $IO ]; do
    IFS=" " read rchart wchart syscrt syscwt rbytest wbytest cwbytest < <(cut -d " " -f2 $IO | tr "\n" " ")

    S=$SECONDS
    [ $S -eq 0 ] && continue

cat << EOF
rchar:                 $((($rchart-$rchar)/1024/1024/$S)) MByte/s
wchar:                 $((($wchart-$wchar)/1024/1024/$S)) MByte/s
syscr:                 $((($syscrt-$syscr)/1024/1024/$S)) MByte/s
syscw:                 $((($syscwt-$syscw)/1024/1024/$S)) MByte/s
read_bytes:            $((($rbytest-$rbytes)/1024/1024/$S)) MByte/s
write_bytes:           $((($wbytest-$wbytest)/1024/1024/$S)) MByte/s
cancelled_write_bytes: $((($cwbytest-$cwbytes)/1024/1024/$S)) MByte/s
EOF
    echo
    sleep $I
done
```

Comment: What of these each values mean? Like for a case of mysql, which value should I be noting down to calculate the exact disk I/O used by my mysql process?

Comment: @Vineeth: This should help you: [Understanding the counters in /proc/pid/io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3634088/3776858)

Comment: Brother, that helped. I'm on a task to migrate my on-premise mysql production installation to RDS. So need to calculate the exact disk I/O used by mysql.