# Script to determine how many KB/sec of IO a PID is using

Tags: linux, bash, io, pid

This is a bit out of my league, but I was wondering if I could write a script that takes a PID as an argument, and tells me how many KB/sec of IO the mentioned PID is using.

1. I don't know how to give an argument to a script
2. I am not sure if the /proc/[PID]/io is actually showing me this info. Is the summation of 'read_bytes' + 'write_bytes' the KB of IO used?
3. How can I update this value every second?

Comment: Take a look at second script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716260/3776858

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus I had a look at the script. I'm still not sure if I should if I should add read_bytes and write_bytes together to get the IO. The process of IO seems the read&write bytes, is that correct?

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question I am very new to these concepts.

Comment: You can find details of read_bytes and write_bytes there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3634088/3776858

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you could use the iotop command. you can use it with just iotop or add the flags "-p <pid>" to monitor just a single process.

Example:

```
sudo iotop -p 7667
```

Comment: Thanks @davvs. I had come across a few tools such as iotop. But I wanted to keep the script in a way that it would not rely on tools that might not be installed on the server, since I want to do this across many servers.