# Disk Utilization stats per POD in K8

Tags: kubernetes

I was looking for ways to get details on disk utilization (mainly writes and Delete's) on a per POD level. I did get google advice such as cAdvisor/heapster etc but none of them talk about disk usage profiling from POD perspective.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the pods are running a linux variant you can do:

```
kubectl exec -it <pod> cat /proc/1/io
```

Returns info on the main process' IO defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633286/understanding-the-counters-in-proc-pid-io)

You could then write a script to run the above command (or use the kuberentes API) for each pod of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But the missing thing with this is to get the actual deleted_bytes from storage by each process. Not sure if we can get those stats somewhere.

Comment: I also see diskstats under /proc so just wanted to know the diff between /proc/pid/io and /proc/diskstats

Comment: does this one show the persistent volumes in kubernetes?

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin that's a different question you can use `get pv` etc. for those details